# Is storing values in TempData safe for multiple concurrent users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've been using TempData to preserve my model in between page requests, as otherwise I lose access to specific properties of classes in the model that I need.

(It's a slight digression and simplification, but basically I have a List of objects which have a .name and a .active property.  I have a CheckBoxFor the .active property, and that is preserved, but the .name property is set to null when the form is submitted; I need access to that property as well, so I've been storing the old model in TempData and then copying over that property when I need it.  Is there a better way of doing that?  I was quite surprised that properties of objects that I'm using would be nulled.)

The model is stored in TempData when the user checks a checkbox, thus submitting the form.  It is read out of TempData at some later time, when the user clicks a button.  (There are no intervening requests.)

Is using TempData in such a way safe for multiple users?  In other words, does each client get its own copy of TempData?  I'm worried about a situation roughly like the following:

1. User 1 clicks checkbox, saving his model to TempData
2. User 2 clicks checkbox, saving her model to TempData
3. User 1 clicks button, submitting the form and reading a model from TempData

What I am unsure about is which model User 1 will get.  Could someone please enilghten me?

Comment: Is storing the data in a JavaScript variable an option for you?  This would maintain state between page requests and would eliminate concurrent user collisions.

Comment: Not easily.  It's a list of objects, each with a name (that I need) and with a list of child objects.  Each of the child objects has a tag (that I need) and the .active property, and the number of parent and child objects varies.  The controller neds to know about all of this at all times (it has to be able to associate each .active state with a name/tag pair), and the view needs to display it.

Comment: OK, going out on a limb here because I only want to help:  This really sounds like the type of thing that could be stored in a JS object on the client.  If you don't need to manipulate the data directly during the request, then I would use something like JsonFX to serialize you model, deliver it to the View, and then store on the client to await further manipulation.  I am doing this on several apps and it works well.  The only *challenge* (not blocker) I have concerns SEO.  Hope this makes sense--just trying to help ;).

Comment: I appreciate the advice.  That sounds somewhat promising, although I really wouldn't know how to do it.  Would your advice stay the same even if I need to construct a server request from the data?  (The name/tag lets me uniquely identify a data series that I can then grab from a database on the server side)

Comment: Hey sapi, admittedly, I am getting a little sloppy for the night, but let me throw out these steps in hopes that they help: 1) download either JSON.Net or JsonFx and reference in your app and then in your .cs or .vb file.  2) construct your model in the usual way.  3) serialize your model using the plugin from step 1 and then make it available to the view via an ASPX page that only outputs JSON or, if MVC, an ActionResult that returns Content(YourSerializedObject,"application/json") 4) Now call your Json via ajax (jQuery Post works) and store it via JS (var data = response).

Comment: I realize that this isn't 100% helpful, but I am getting pulled away for more holiday cheer with family.  I will check tomorrow to see if you have had more help and, if not, see what else I can offer.  Good luck & Cheers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TempData is session bound. User 1 will only see its TempData.

Comment: Thanks :)  Is there a more logical way in MVC to force model state to persist?  I've never understood why the view doesn't just operate on the instance of the model it was created with, rather than throwing away all properties that aren't explicitly bound to something.

Comment: Its the nature of HTTP. A view and a controller represent one HTTP request and response.

Comment: The only other way to persist model data without showing it is with hidden inputs.